# How to implement qr-code inside a pdf file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, qr-code

I was trying to implement generation of pdf file, and when user downloads this pdf, he should get pdf with qr-code inside of it. I have managed to implement pdf generation, but i can't set a qr-code there. Will be really thankful for your help!

Also i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: qrcode_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.toDataURL 
is not a function
```

Here is what i have so far:

````
import { Page, Text, Document, StyleSheet, Image } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import QRCode from "qrcode.react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginBottom: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "grey",
  },
  text: {
    margin: 12,
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: "justify",
    fontFamily: "Times-Roman",
  },
  qrcode: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
});

const PdfFile = () => {
  const url = "https://www.example.com"; // Your URL here
  const [qrcodeDataUrl, setQRCodeDataUrl] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const generateQRCode = async () => {
      try {
        const dataUrl = await QRCode.toDataURL(url);
        setQRCodeDataUrl(dataUrl);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    generateQRCode();
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <Text style={styles.header} fixed>
          EUROPEAN ONLINE BORDER
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Have a good trip!</Text>
        <Text>My QR Code:</Text>
        {qrcodeDataUrl && (
          <Image
            src={`data:image/png;base64,${qrcodeDataUrl.split(",")[1]}`}
            style={styles.qrcode}
          />
        )}
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

export default PdfFile;``` 


Also i am getting this error:
TypeError: qrcode_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.toDataURL is not a function
````

Comment: It looks like the way you are using it is deprecated as seen in the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode.react

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine if you instead install the `qrcode` package, at https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode. The default export from that package has the `toDataURL` method that you want to use.

As Nick mentioned in his comment, `qrcode.react` has deprecated that export. Additionally, it exports that module but a limited(stripped down?) version, and if you want the method `toDataURL` you will need the original module.